# Holomorphic function with uncountable set of zeros?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am aware that on a region, this is only possible if the function is identical to zero. If the domain is not a region, is it possible to have a non-trivial holomorphic function with uncountable zero set?

Comment: What's the difference between a domain and a region?

Comment: A region is connected.

Answer (score 3):

If your function is not zero everywhere, its zeroes are isolated. In other words, for each zero $z$ you can find a disk $D_z$ containing $z$ in which it is the only zero. Now choose a point with rational coordinates in each $D_z$, and you get an injection from the set of zeroes to $\mathbf Q^2$, which is countable, so the set of zeroes is also countable.

---

I appear to have misread your question. What I said above is true only if the domain on which you're working is connected. If not, the function can be zero on some connected components and non-zero on others, so in that case, yes, the set of zeroes can be uncountable.

Example: consider two disjoint disks $D$ and $D'$, and define $f$ to be $0$ on $D$ and $1$ on $D'$; then $f$ is holomorphic, and its zero set is a whole disk.

Comment: Ok. What about a limit point. Can the zero set ever have a limit point?

Comment: No, the zero set is discrete.

Comment: The previous comment holds when the domain is connected. See my edit in the answer.

Comment: What about $\sin \frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: @hardmath I don't understand what you mean. What about $\sin 1/x$ indeed?

Comment: Thank you jathd. So am I correct to say that the function must be locally identical to zero, in order to have an uncountable zero set?

Comment: @Michael No, it doesn't have to be locally zero; the example function $f$ I defined isn't. I don't think there's much more to say when the domain isn't connected, other than if a connected component contains uncountably many zeroes, then the function is identically zero on that component.

Comment: @jathd: I mean that $\sin \frac{1}{x}$ is holomorphic in the punctured plane (a connected domain), and that its zeroes have a limit point (notwithstanding the fact that each zero is isolated).

Comment: @hardmath Oh, right. The definition of limit point that I had in mind was wrong. So the zero set is discrete, but that doesn't prevent it from having a limit point (in $\mathbf C$).

Comment: I upvoted your answer by the way; the limit point question was something the OP only tossed into the comments.  Good job!